# pushViewController doesn't work after an Xcode 9 update

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, xcode9

I use a xib not a storyBord.
The problem is when i want to change windows on the application.
I can load the next window but i can't display it with pushViewController,i'm informing you that worked before updating Xcode.

Thanx for your responses
Button click method  :

```
`MesFic *vueMesFic=[[MesFic alloc] initWithNibName:@"MesFic" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vueMesFic animated:YES];
[vueMesFic release];
vueMesFic=nil;`
```

my appDelegate.m

```
MyStyleSheet * myStyleSheetInstance = [[MyStyleSheet alloc] init];
[TTStyleSheet setGlobalStyleSheet:myStyleSheetInstance];
[myStyleSheetInstance release];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

//[self.window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[window setRootViewController:navigationController];
return YES;
```

Comment: I am sure, you got error here `[vueMesFic release];`

Comment: Add in main queue.

Comment: Make sure application window has navigationController.

Comment: Is `self.navigationController` nil? You do just after `vueMesFic=nil;` ?

Comment: No `self.navigationController ` isn't nil

Comment: I haven't the choice to use Swift, my appDelegate:
`MyStyleSheet * myStyleSheetInstance = [[MyStyleSheet alloc] init];
[TTStyleSheet setGlobalStyleSheet:myStyleSheetInstance];
[myStyleSheetInstance release];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

//[self.window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[window setRootViewController:navigationController];
return YES;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using navigationController then, make sure that you have set navigationController as your root controller.

```
MyStyleSheet * myStyleSheetInstance = [[MyStyleSheet alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myStyleSheetInstance];
[window setRootViewController:navigationController];
```

In this case, you can use self.navigation for navigation

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vueMesFic animated:YES];
```

If you are not willing to use UINavigation,

```
 MyStyleSheet * myStyleSheetInstance = [[MyStyleSheet alloc] init];
[window setRootViewController:myStyleSheetInstance];
```

then use

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It may help you